# wordpress Front End PM

Tags: wordpress, plugins

i use the plugin Front End PM
https://he.wordpress.org/plugins/front-end-pm/

And i wonder how can i make an private message throw the PHP code and not as a frontend user , i search all over here and the docs of the plugin and i found out that there is a function call 'fep_save_message' , but with no success on it...

can someone help ? , if you know other plugin that can help me throw code send a private message i want to know .

Thanks :) !

Answer (score 0):

In last project we use BuddyPress and BuddyPress private message https://buddypress.org/about/private-messaging/ this work very nice.

You may try use https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-recall/ but this is add not only PW.

Comment: i need a very simple thing that allow to user see a message - can be able to send message with PHP CODE - for example : send_message($user_id)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fep_send_message()` function to send message. It supports directly post data or you can pass data as argument.

**Example**

```
$message = array(
    'message_title' => 'Title of your message',
    'message_content'   => 'Content of your message',
    'message_to_id' => 123, //Receiver id
);

$message_id = fep_send_message( $message );
```